# RDLC report - Duplicate data issue in grouping

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-expression

I have a RDLC report in which I want grouping by username and status which has value open and closed. I am getting duplicate username when both the value of status is present for the username.

In the expression, I have used below code -

```
=IIf (
Fields!Status.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim() = "open",
Count(Fields!Status.Value),
0 )

=IIf (
Fields!Status.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim() = "closed",
Count(Fields!Status.Value),
0)
```

My output is this one - [Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qs9r.png)

And I want this output - [Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJqaz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use a matrix instead of a table.

You can then have a rowgroup by `Username`, a column group by `Status` and then the value would simple be `=CountRows()`

So, using your sample data as my dataset query.

```
declare @t table (UserName varchar(10), [Status] varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('User1', 'Closed'),
('User2', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User3', 'Closed'),
('User4', 'Closed'),
('User4', 'Closed'),
('User4', 'Closed'),
('User4', 'Open')

select * from @t
```

Create a new report and add a matrix control.

Drag the fields to the respective column and rows headers as shown below.
[image]

Next, set the Value cell's expression to `=CountRows()`

This will give us a basic matrix output.

[image]

Next to add the totals...

In the row and column group panel below the main design window, right-click the group, then select "add total" then "After", repeat this for both row and column groups.

Set the expression for the new cells to, again, `=CountRows()`

The final design looks like this.

[image]

(note all the cells that show expression are set the the same `=CountRows()` expression.)

The final output looks like this (after a bit of bold and shading)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It works fine now.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered you question, can you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I did that but as I am a new user so it gives me this message - "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: Don't  use the voting buttons, click the 'check mark' under them. Take a look at this article for guidance. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers